# Echo to file descriptor overwrites the file?

Tags: bash, files, exec

I am having trouble understanding what is happening when I try to write to a file descriptor? It appears to be overwriting the original contents? Is this expected behaviour?

I have replicated this in the example below:

```
$ echo "The quick brown fox ..." > example.txt  
$ echo "The quick brown fox ..." >> example.txt
$ cat example.txt
The quick brown fox ...  
The quick brown fox ...
$ exec 88<>example.txt
$ cat example.txt
The quick brown fox ...  
The quick brown fox ...
$ echo "jumped" >&88  
$ cat example.txt
jumped  
ck brown fox ...  
The quick brown fox ...
$ echo "jumped" >&88  
$ cat example.txt
jumped  
jumped  
n fox ...  
The quick brown fox ...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you hadn't done any reads on descriptor 88, the current seek position was "0", and so the write took place at that point.

If, instead, you'd read the file before then, then appends happen:

```
bash-4.2$ cat <&88
The quick brown fox ...
The quick brown fox ...

bash-4.2$ echo hello >&88

bash-4.2$ cat example.txt 
The quick brown fox ...
The quick brown fox ...
hello

bash-4.2$ echo more >&88

bash-4.2$ cat example.txt 
The quick brown fox ...
The quick brown fox ...
hello
more
```

Comment: Wow! So this means that the file descriptor (in this example 88) maintains a separate seek position to the standard cat? i.e. cat example.txt

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Just tested this out and you are right. Interestingly enough, if  I continue to echo out to the file again, and then echo to the descriptor (without reading on the descriptor) the problem persists. So if other processes are writing to the file, then I need to constantly read in on the descriptor, before writing out!

Comment: @Zoonose: When you execute `cat example.txt`, cat opens the file, getting a descriptor with a seek position starting at the beginning of the file, reads it until the end, and then closes the descriptor.  When you execute `exec 88<>example.txt`, _bash_ opens the file, getting a descriptor with a seek position starting at the beginning of the file.  The file itself doesn't maintain a seek position, instead a position is maintained for each open file descriptor.

Comment: Even if you `cat <&88` first, the following writes are just regular writes to the position where the writing stopped, not proper appends. They might overwrite data written by another process in the meanwhile. If appending is what is wanted, then the `>>` redirection operator is the (only) way to go. As far as I know, Bash doesn't really have a way to seek files, and it also doesn't allow opening with both read/write-mode _and_ append-mode at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

As @Zoonose correctly points out, each filedescriptor has its own read-write cursor position within the file that it's connected to. And a file can be opened either by the shell when you use a redirection such as `<>`, or by a program such as `cat`.

But the numbers that you think of as "a filedescriptor" are just references to the actual filedescriptors within the kernel, and it's entirely normal for one filedescriptor to have multiple such reference numberss, either within a single process, or between processes.

So when you open a terminal window (or log in by ssh), you start with a single filedescriptor open to your terminal, connected as fd#0, fd#1 & fd#2 in your shell process. Any process that the shell starts with inherit these by default -- except where you've used pipes or redirections.

The redirection `>>` flags the filedescriptor as `O_APPEND`, so that writes through *that* filedescriptor ignore the cursor and go onto the end of the file.

The redirection `>` causes the target file to be truncated just once, *before* any writing is done. Thus any writing after that *normally* goes into the empty space past the end of the file.

Writes to a file do *not* themselves cause truncation; they will simply replace whatever is at the current position, and stretch the end-of-file if necessary.

Note that `somecmd >&88` will cause the stdout (fd#1) for somecmd to share the filedescriptor with fd#88 of the current shell. That means it will share the `O_APPEND` option, if present. It *won't* cause it to be truncated again; that's a one-time thing.

What you're seeing in the case is that there's no *additional* truncation when you use `>&88`, and (because fd#88 wasn't opened using `>>`) it can overwrite existing data.